# Как выбрать потомка jquery

Tags: jquery

есть страница вот код

```
<div class="link lux">LUX
 <div class="child">
  <p class="text"> тут какой-нибудь текст</р>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="link vip">V.I.P
 <div class="child">
  <p class="text"></p>
 </div>
</div>
```

надо чтобы при нажатии на LUX вываливалось окошко с класом child потомок <div class="link lux"> а при нажатии на V.I.P окошко с класом child потомок <div class="link vip"> на  я прописываю следующий код

```
$('.link').click(function(){
 $($(this)>'.child').css({"display":"block"});
})
```

как вы понимаете ни чего не получаетьс может посоветуете что делать ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почти верно писали:

```
$('.link').click(function(){
  $('> .child', $(this)).show();
});
```

По поводу show. show добавит стиль элементу, т.е. inline-style, который перебьет любые другие стили (из .css в частности).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click','.link',function(){
    $(this).find('.child').show();
})
```

Comment: а если .child в стилях присвоен display none

Comment: jQuery разберется, что там у .child :) 

.show() и предназначен, чтобы показывать скрытые элементы.

Comment: без  разницы

Comment: @Кудрин Сергей тут видимо нужен прямой потомок, так что


     $(this).children('.child').show();

@Sergalas  только непонятно зачем вам подчеркивать чилдовость ещё и классом.

     $(this).children().show(); вполне нормальный вариант.

Comment: Поставьте ; в конце моего кода. И покажите, что пишет Ваш скрипт  в консоль.

Comment: @eicto Согласен, но, глядя на качество кода, пусть лучше так, на будущее.

Comment: Все работает но а)у меня уже включен документ ( $(document).ready(function(){) то есть незнаю нужен ли $(document).on б) мне надо при клике .link надо убрать обший фон который храниться с другом элементе который родитель .link  в) выключить окно элементом .close в элементе .child